# Social network for internal company use

Tags: intranet, social-networking, private-network

I'm seeking a social network app for employees in the company that can do the following:

- allows people to communicate within a company or across everyone on the social network (they can have access to a group or to everyone)
- post and archive interesting links, documents, etc.
- start a thread that goes to a group or to everyone
- lookup people’s info (profile)
- integrate w email so I can know if someone posts something new or responds to a questions
- Open source + customized deployment is a plus.

Comment: You should probably look at Yammer. Unfortunately your question is out of SuperUser's scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

www.manymoon.com is probably the best I've seen. It integrates exclusively with Google Apps, so it wont work if you're not using Google Apps. But really, use Google Apps.